# maximal code reuse in a Python decorator with arguments

Tags: python, decorator

I managed to write a decorator that takes arguments, but I'm bothered by the fact that both actual decorators have the same lines of code:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    r = fn(*args)
```

and was wondering if there were some way to fix this violation of DRY

```
def fix(double):
    def outer(fn):
        if double:
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                r = fn(*args)
                return 2 * r
            return wrapper
        else:
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                r = fn(*args)
                return r
            return wrapper
    return outer
```

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply by 1 if double is False:

```
def fix(double):
    def outer(fn):
        factor = 2 if double else 1
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            r = fn(*args)
            return factor * r
        return wrapper
    return outer
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand if you don't reuse `double` as a variable name.  Call it `factor` or `multiplier` maybe?

Comment: I took the freedom to rename the new variable to `factor`, which seems less confusing to me.  Please roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach But you edited after I changed, so it's the same thing :)

Comment: Oh, did not notice.  So you obviously agree with this edit. :)  My edit was 4 seconds after yours…

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be

```
def fix(double):
    def outer(fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            r = fn(*args, **kwargs) # do that right!
            return 2 * r if double else r
        return wrapper
    return outer
```

or even - as you don't change anything if `double` is `False` -:

```
def fix(double):
    def outer(fn):
        if not double: return fn
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            r = fn(*args, **kwargs) # do that right!
            return 2 * r
        return wrapper
    return outer
```